# Invoke printscreen functionality on button click

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I am using angular2 and i am trying to invoke the printscreen functionality from a page using a button and button click method.

What i am trying to do is once i click the button i must invoke the hostlistener for the button press event and take a screenshot of the entire screen and not just the window.

My code is as follows:
in screenshot.component.html page:

```
<button (click) ="onkeydownHandler($event)">Capture</button>
```

in the screenshot.component.ts file:

```
export class ScreenshotComponent{

    onkeydownHandler(event: MouseEvent) {

        @HostListener('window:keyup', event.keyCode='44')
        keyEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) {
            console.log(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Since the keycode for the printscreen button is 44 i using that code and trying to invoke the action of the printscreen button.
I am getting the following exception while trying to execute this:

```
ReferenceError: keyEvent is not defined
    at ScreenshotComponent.onkeydownHandler (screenshot.component.ts:14)
    at ChangeDetector_ScreenshotComponent_0.handleEventInternal (viewFactory_ScreenshotComponent:30)
    at ChangeDetector_ScreenshotComponent_0.AbstractChangeDetector.handleEvent (angular2.dev.js:9568)
    at AppView.triggerEventHandlers (angular2.dev.js:10246)
    at eval (viewFactory_ScreenshotComponent:84)
    at angular2.dev.js:14068
    at angular2.dev.js:13496
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:332)
    at Object.onInvoke (angular2.dev.js:2111)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (angular2-polyfills.js:331)
```

Is this the right way to do? Can someone please help?

Comment: you can't invoke print screen from the browser, thats up to the operating system.

Comment: But,@DanielA.White web clients like webex allow us to capture or share our screen dont they? Is there no way we can do that?

Comment: I agree with Daniel, this is not something you can do with JavaScript in a browser.

Comment: @Dhirish - Those clients require you to install software to the OS.

Comment: @Dhirish there’s webrtc

Comment: @DanielA.White How to can i use it to take a screenshot? Will these allow me to take it?

Comment: @TravisJ is there anyother way using angular?

Comment: Angular is just glorified JavaScript :)

Comment: The addons like html2canvas are allowing me to only take a screenshot of the page and not their entire screen. That is why i tried doing this way

Comment: @Dhirish Javascript doesn't have access to anything outside the page.

Comment: @Barmar is there any api that can be coupled with this so as to brng out the functionality?

Comment: @Dhirish Several people have already told you this can't be done using JS.

Comment: @Amy ok , quick question, is there any other web app i can use for this functionality